# fusebox 5.5 noxml folder name problems

Tags: view, coldfusion, model, cfc, fusebox

I am having trouble with fusebox 5.5 noxml and circuits...

I have a structure that looks like this.

```
controller
 app.cfc
model
 main
  act_comm_main.cfm
 monkey
  act_something_else.cfm
view
 main
  dsp_comm_main.cfm
 monkey
  dsp_somethingElse.cfm
```

In the app.cfc file I have this:

```
<cffunction name="postfuseaction">
    <cfargument name="myFusebox" />
    <cfargument name="event" />

    <!--- do the layout --->
    <cfset myFusebox.do( action="layout.lay_template" ) />

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="main">
    <cfargument name="myFusebox" />
    <cfargument name="event" />

    <!--- do model fuse --->
    <cfset myFusebox.do( action="moneky.act_somethingElse" ) />

    <!--- do model fuse --->
    <cfset myFusebox.do( action="main.act_comm_main" ) />

    <!--- do display fuse and set content variable body --->
    <cfset myFusebox.do( action="main.dsp_comm_main", contentvariable="body" ) />

</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

This doesn't work. but if I change it to have the view folder named: mainPages so and then change the cfset myFusebox. do to look at mainPages.dsp_comm_main (it comes up) but in the instance above it give me this error:

> undefined Fuseaction
>
> You specified a Fuseaction of dsp_comm_main which is not defined in
>   Circuit main.

I remove the parsed files and let fusebox rebuild but I still get this error.

So I know how to work around it by naming my directories different between the model and view folders but why is this happening and what can I do to get to resolve same named directories across the model view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in Fusebox models and views are just a convention to implement MVC. Technically they just a circuits, explicit or implicit, doesn't matter.

Circuit name must be unique within the application, so you have to name the folders differently.

Personaly I've used naming like `vMain/mMain`, `vMonkey/mMonkey` for more complex apps with many view circuits. For simpler apps it could be enough to have just `layout` and `display` view circuits, this way models can be named without prefix.